# Sort by dates in excel when the date is custom format

Tags: excel, sorting, date

i want to sort by date in excel. I've made the steps but it takes only the first argument which is the day. My format of dates is this:

```
22/Mar/23 9:27 AM
17/Mar/23 5:03 PM
27/Feb/23 11:01 AM
10/Feb/23 12:03 PM
05/Jan/23 9:55 AM
09/Dec/22 5:19 PM
08/Sep/22 2:05 PM
```

and the default sort is taking into account only the first argument as i mentioned before. Do you know how to achieve the desired sorting functionality?

Comment: Are you sure you have the input as date data type? It seems that you have the date as text, if so you would need to convert it first. Are you using an excel formula for sorting or Excel sort functionality that comes in the menu?

Comment: NumberFormat of a date makes no difference in sorting. Dates are stored as decimal numbers. However, if you have your dates stored as text strings, then you should convert them to" real dates" for sorting purposes. Numerous examples on this forum for doing so.

Comment: I agree with @RonRosenfeld Sir ^^^, however personally, while working with bank statements and when sometimes the dates are formatted as text, i use the `Text To Columns` aka `TTC` and sort it accordingly as per the need. Usually it works great!